# String replace javascript , setting an alias or Label

Tags: javascript, string, replace

at the moment the data being put into the database when initial_enquiries is selected is "initial_enquiries" Which is want. Its also displaying this in the drop down as the value , i dont want it to be that i want it to say "initial enquiries" in the drop down with no underscore

```
$('#account-status').css({'cursor':'pointer'}).click(function() {
            // Create an array of status
            var statuses = new Array;
            statuses.push('initial_enquiries')
            statuses.push('active');
            statuses.push('discontinue');
            statuses.push('pending');
            statuses.push('suspended');

            // Get the account statuses
            $(this).hide().after('<select id="select-status" class="form_s"></select>');
            $('#select-status').append('<option value="">-Select-</option');

            $.each(statuses, function(i, v) {
                $('#select-status').append('<option value="' + v + '">' + v.capitalize() + '</option>');
            });
```

Comment: Tip: You can push many items at once. Also you can use literal array syntax and save 5 lines.

Comment: Its laid out this for logic to be easily added in

Answer (score 1):

In your case this should be enough:

replace you `v.capitalize()` with this:

```
    v.replace('_', ' ').capitalize();
```

As I said this is for your case you show us in you question but I wouldn't use this if the array is generated automatically.

Comment: In you loop you have this `$('#select-status').append('<option value="' + v + '">' + v.capitalize() + '</option>');` simply replace that line with this one: `$('#select-status').append('<option value="' + v + '">' + v.replace('_', ' ').capitalize() + '</option>');`